# Atomic operations with DerbyJS

Tags: atomic, derbyjs

Are there any atomic operations with DerbyJS? [From the documentation](http://derbyjs.com/#mutators) it seems there are no operations like MongoDB `addToSet`? How does one implement this?

Answer (score 0):

There are `model.setNull` and `model.setDiff` operations. But there is no equivalent to `addToSet`.